# mysqli select query is taking long time in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 13,000 records in my database table. When I pose a query `SELECT * FORM table_name` in a php page and looping through the result it was taking almost 20 seconds. I am using mysqli to access the database. What might be the problem. How could i improve the performance.

And without looping through the table,can i get the entire table in two dimensional array.

Comment: After the 20 seconds, are the results displaying correctly?

Comment: How long does the query take if you just run it in phpMyAdmin or whatever mysql client you're using?

Comment: Lets see a `show create table $table` along with the query you're running.

Comment: Are you trying to display all 13,000 rows in a web page? If it's in an HTML table, the browser will take a long time to render it.

Comment: Does your query run faster in *mysql* command line/*phpmyadmin*?

Comment: @TerryHarvey yeah it was showing the correct results

Comment: @SomeSillyName It was taking less than half a second in phpmyadmin

Comment: @TerryHarvey No when i fetch all 13000 records it doesn't show up any thing, but if search with some condition it was taking around 20 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using PDO for this instead of MySQLi? PDO's `fetchAll()` method returns the entire result set in a single array without manually looping through and creating the array.

```
$server = '127.0.0.1';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$database = 'database';

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$database;host=$server", $username, $password);
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
$result_array = $sth->fetchAll();
```